# Is that official SO firefox ad-on

Tags: discussion

I have just stumbled upon this: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/14532

Answer (score 4):

"Official" as in built and/or endorsed by Jeff/Joel? No.

[It was built by a member for other members.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23699/firefox-addon-for-stackoverflow-trilogy-sites)

Comment: that's what I thought

Answer (score 1):

I'd already added the search functionality to Firefox with the ['Add to Search Bar'](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3682) add-on, so there's nothing exciting yet.  I think the rep and badges showing on the bar will be interesting, so we'll see how that goes.

Here's the [Meta SO link](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3682) on how to setup the Firefox search for all four sites.